# GitHub Octokit/rest.js OAuth for Single Page Applications

Tags: javascript, github, oauth, single-page-application, octokit

I am using the GitHub API client '[octokit/rest.js](https://github.com/octokit/rest.js)' in an Angular single page application (SPA). Given that it is generally more secure and that I use 2 factor authentication for my GitHub account (password alone is not enough) I wanted to make use of the OAuth workflow. I've been following the instructions [here](https://developer.github.com/apps/building-oauth-apps/authorizing-oauth-apps/) for obtaining an access token and then use this to build the octokit client:

```
login(token: string) {
  this.client = new Octokit({
    auth: `token ${token}`
  });
}
```

In order to fetch the token I've had to make a simple backend, whose purpose is simply to get the token and pass it to the front-end, as I haven't worked out how to do this securely from within the SPA (it requires a client_secret which I can't keep secure on the front end?). It seems to to work but I'm still left with important questions:

- Is this secure? Or should the access token be kept only server side?
- Is there a better way of handling octokit/GitHub API auth from the front end only?

Answer (score 6):

`ocotkit/rest.js` maintainer here

The `client_secret` cannot be shared with the client. The OAuth flow requires a backend which keeps the `client_secret` secure.

An alternative is to create a token using your username & password, in that case you don’t need a server component. But usually users might be reluctant to share their login credentials with an external website. But for personal/internal projects it might be the simplest way to do it.

```js
let octokit = new Octokit({
  auth: {
    username: USERNAME,
    password: PASSWORD,
    on2fa () {
      return prompt('Enter code')
    }
  }
})

octokit.oauthAuthorizations.createAuthorization({
  scopes: [], // add scopes
  note: 'token description'
})

  .then(({ data: { token } }) => {
    octokit = new Octokit({ auth: 'token ${token}' })
    // octokit is now authenticated with token
  })
```

Note that the token `note` must be unique. If you created a token with the same note before, you will need to use a different note or delete the existing token first.

We are currently considering to add more `auth.*` options, so that a token gets created for you internally before any request is sent. We are discussing this change at https://github.com/octokit/rest.js/pull/1293 if you are interested

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Gregor! Yes I aware that client secrets should not be shared on the front-end. This is why I have the minimalistic backend in place which has the single job of getting a token and passing it to the front-end. However, I'm still not sure if that's secure as if the communication between the server/front-end is intercepted could an attacker not take the token and use it themselves? My specific project is [here](https://github.com/Peter554/github-repo-tagger) if that helps to clarify my current architecture.

Comment: As long as the the server is secured with SSL there should be no problem.